# I want to transfer My fund To My old Mutlibit Core to Other Wallet

Tags: multibit

MY MULTIBIT CORE WALLET IS LOCKED I'M NOT ABLE TO ACCESS TRANSFER FUND IS THERE ANY WAY TO TRASFER MY ALL FUND TO OTHER WALLET PLEASE HELP ME BECAUSE I RECOVERED MY OLD ACCOUNT SO MUCH AFFERT BUT NOW I CAN'T TRANSFER MY FUND

Comment: What is MULTIBIT?

Comment: By "Multibit Core" do you mean https://www.multibitwallet.io/ or the old, long dead [multibit legacy and multibit-HD wallets](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/multibit). If someone is asking you for money to unlock your wallet it means you have been scammed and you have no funds and there is no way to retrieve funds because they have been stolen or are fake.

Comment: Note: The multibitwallet.io domain was only registered yesterday and looks like some sort of scam to me.